# Could not open libreoffice "general error in central configuration file"

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

Problem:

Today I attempted to open a document with libreoffice. I got the error "could not open application. There is a general error in your central configuration file."
Naturally I opened up my configuration editor and started looking for keys related to libreoffice. Couldn't find any.
Tried reinstalling. Didn't work.
Tried uninstalling and installing open office. Didn't work.

System:
Ubuntu 11.10
GNOME3

### Any ideas?

Update:
I get the following when attempting to run from terminal:
`[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed! 
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'`

Comment: Did you `purge` openoffice before re-installing? Did you try to rename the old settings directory `~/.openoffice.org/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appearing in the terminal (`javaldx failed`) points to a problem regarding the user config directory. I assume that deinstalling OpenOffice.org doesn't modify the user's config (even purging - `apt-get purge ...` - leaves those contents untouched), so removing or (better!) renaming the user config directory may help. It's placed in `~/.openoffice.org/` since OpenOffice.org 3.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with the latest libreoffice on a production machine.

```
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)
```

To fix:

```
sudo apt -y install libreoffice-base
```

This will install all the requirements for libreoffice including the java-jre which appears to your issue